# What happens when the number of bits required to represent possible values in constraint (var inside {[x:y]};) exceed the rand variable width?

Tags: system-verilog

For the following class:

```
class CPacket;
  int offset;
  rand bit [3:0] sa, da;
  int lo = 2, hi = 10;

  constraint LimitA {
    sa inside {[lo:hi]};
    da inside {[lo:hi]};
  }

  function void pre_randomize();
    if(this.offset) begin
      lo = lo + offset;
      hi = hi + offset;
    end
  endfunction
endclass
```

If I want to run this:

```
CPacket pkt = new();
pkt.offset = 100;
pkt.randomize();
```

Will it fail because that offset value makes the new `lo` and `hi` define a range of values that does not match 4-bit vector width?

Will it succeed and take the 4 LSBs of the new `lo` and `hi` to define the range of values that `sa` and `da` can have?

What happens in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expressions used in a constraint behave the same as if they were used outside a constraint. There are only 16 possible values for `sa` and `da` and if you tried all of them (4'b0000 through 4'b1111), none of them would makes the `inside` expression return true for the example you show.

It's the same as if you wrote `sa >= lo && sa <= hi`. Verilog zero extends the shorter unsigned operand to match the width of the longer operand.

Answer (score 2):

`randomize` will fail because that offset value makes the new `lo` and `hi` define a range of values that does not match 4-bit vector width.  `sa` can not be in the range of 102-110 because its valid range is 0-15.  You can prove this by checking the return value of `randomize`: 1=pass, 0=fail.

From IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 18.6.3 *Behavior of randomization methods*:

> If randomize() fails, the constraints are infeasible, and the random
> variables retain their previous values

You can confirm this by displaying the values before and after you call `randomize`:

```
module tb;
    CPacket pkt = new();
    initial begin
        pkt.offset = 100;
        $display("sa=%0d", pkt.sa);
        if (pkt.randomize()) begin
            $display("PASS");
        end else begin
            $display("FAIL");
        end
        $display("sa=%0d", pkt.sa);
    end
endmodule
```

You will see output similar to this:

```
sa=0
[Possible simulator-specific warnings about randomize failing]
FAIL
sa=0
```